# REST & MySQL offset selection

Tags: php, mysql, rest

I have REST service and method which receives properties **offset** and **count**.

> Example of url : blablabla?offset=10&count=10

Let's imagine that i am selecting data for infinite scroll and my site has many users so when i scrolls down i have new items in database it means that when i select **offset** 10 and **count** 10 it has new 10 items, so I'll select same data. Does MySQL has some tricks to prevent it, and select it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your data into a defined, reproducible order; meaning sort it by something like date or id or so in which the order is stable every time you sort it. Then use the date/id/whatever of the last item in the list as "offset":

```
bla?last=12345&count=10

  SELECT *
    FROM foo
   WHERE id < [last id]
ORDER BY id DESC
   LIMIT [count]
```

In this case, when using ids, you need to make sure your ids are always incrementing so newer records always have a higher id than older records. Alternatively use another criterium to sort/offset by.